# Count case is returning a wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying get count of orders that are closed in less than 30 min and more than 30 min.

Table structure & sample data

```
ORDERID  CUSTOMERID  ORDERDATE              CLOSEDDATE               STATUSID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14        1         2018-07-03 11:02:54.000 2018-07-03 13:15:58.000  CLOSED
15        1         2018-07-03 13:22:42.000 NULL                     DISPATCHED
16        1         2018-07-03 13:26:04.000 NULL                     DISPATCHED
17        1         2018-07-03 13:27:57.000 2018-07-03 13:28:28.000  CLOSED
18        1         2018-07-03 17:23:45.000 NULL                     RECEIVED
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    OUTLETNAME,
    COUNT(ORDERID) AS ORDERSCOUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.CUSTOMERID)) AS CUSTOMERCOUNT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.ORDERDATE, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.CLOSEDDATE) < 30 AND dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.STATUSID = 'CLOSED'   
                  THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0
          END) [LESS 30 (CLOSED)],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.ORDERDATE, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.CLOSEDDATE) > 30 AND dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.STATUSID = 'CLOSED'   
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 
          END) [Greater 30 (CLOSED)]
FROM 
    dbo.VW_SALES_SUM
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[OUTLET] ON dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.OUTLETCODE = dbo.[OUTLET].CODE
WHERE 
    dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.ORDERDATE BETWEEN '7/3/2018 11:00:00 AM' AND '7/4/2018 02:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY 
    OUTLETNAME, dbo.OUTLET.BRAND
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(ORDERID) DESC
```

Output:

```
OUTLETNAME  ORDERSCOUNT CUSTOMERCOUNT   LESS 30 (CLOSED)    IN 30 (CLOSED)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
shop1        5           1              5                   5
```

From the output we can see that it's returning a wrong count of closed orders, it's always returning the total number of orders.

Output should be like this:

```
OUTLETNAME  ORDERSCOUNT CUSTOMERCOUNT   LESS 30 (CLOSED)    Greater 30 (CLOSED)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
shop1        5           1              0                   2
```

Comment: `0` and `1` are both non-null and so an expression that yields either one will be `COUNT`-ed once for each row. Did you intend to `SUM()` instead?

Comment: I used same concept of sum but i need to count in this case

Comment: How many items are in this list - 0, 1, 0, 0, 1? Five, right? so that's what `COUNT` is giving you. If you want to *add those numbers together*, use `SUM` (or take out the `ELSE` clauses from your `CASE`, letting it produce `NULL` in such cases, that then will not be counted)

Comment: Change to SUM instead of COUNT

Comment: Thanks Damien for the help

Comment: `COUNT` counts non-null values, and 0 and 1 are both non-null. Change to `SUM` or better... eliminate the ELSE part in your CASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of counting both 1 and 0.  All you have to do is NOT count both.

The thing is, a count by value doesn't count the NULL's.
But when the CASE WHEN only returns values 0 or 1, the COUNT behaves no different from a COUNT(*).  Since it doesn't return any NULL's for the COUNT to ignore.

So just remove those `ELSE 0` and it'll be fine.

Btw, using alias names can shorten your SQL.

```
SELECT
    OUTLETNAME,
    COUNT(ORDERID) AS ORDERSCOUNT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(s.CUSTOMERID)) AS CUSTOMERCOUNT,
    COUNT(CASE 
          WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, s.ORDERDATE, s.CLOSEDDATE) < 30 AND s.STATUSID = 'CLOSED'   
          THEN 1
          END) [LESS 30 (CLOSED)],
    COUNT(CASE 
          WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, s.ORDERDATE, s.CLOSEDDATE) > 30 AND s.STATUSID = 'CLOSED'   
          THEN 1
          END) [Greater 30 (CLOSED)]
FROM dbo.VW_SALES_SUM s
JOIN dbo.[OUTLET] o ON o.CODE = s.OUTLETCODE
WHERE 
    s.ORDERDATE BETWEEN '7/3/2018 11:00:00 AM' AND '7/4/2018 02:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY OUTLETNAME, o.BRAND
ORDER BY COUNT(ORDERID) DESC
```

You could also just replace the COUNT by a SUM.  But a COUNT has the advantage that you can combine it with a DISTINCT to only count the unique values that aren't NULL.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN col1='bar' then col2 END) AS Bars FROM Foo;
```

Comment: I searched for so long why my query makes wrong count. .. And then removing this simple line `ELSE 0`. .. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of count use SUM

```
SELECT
    OUTLETNAME,
    COUNT(ORDERID) AS ORDERSCOUNT,
    COUNT(distinct(dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.CUSTOMERID)) as CUSTOMERCOUNT,
    SUM(case when DATEDIFF(mi, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.ORDERDATE, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.CLOSEDDATE) < 30 and dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.STATUSID='CLOSED'   then 1 else 0 end) [LESS 30 (CLOSED)],
    SUM(case when DATEDIFF(mi, dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.ORDERDATE,  dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.CLOSEDDATE) > 30 and dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.STATUSID='CLOSED'   then 1 else 0 end) [Greater 30 (CLOSED)]
FROM 
    dbo.VW_SALES_SUM
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[OUTLET] ON dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.OUTLETCODE = dbo.[OUTLET].CODE
WHERE 
    dbo.VW_SALES_SUM.ORDERDATE BETWEEN '7/3/2018 11:00:00 AM' AND '7/4/2018 02:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY 
    OUTLETNAME, dbo.OUTLET.BRAND
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(ORDERID) DESC
```